# Iterating through a vector of abstract classes

Tags: c++, stl, abstract-class

I have the following classes.  An error occurs during the for loop in the `Main` class.  The compiler complains about the `draw` function "is of non-type GLCommand".  The idea of the application is to store many different types of `GLCommand` and `Shape` within the same vector.  Should I take a different design approach, or is their a simple fix to this problem?

Interface:

```
class GLCommand
{
    public:
        GLCommand();
        virtual ~GLCommand();
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};
```

Abstract Class:

```
class Shape : public GLCommand
{
public:
  Shape(int);
  virtual ~Shape();
  virtual void draw() {};
private:
  double colour[];
  int sides;

};
```

Derived class:

```
class Polygon : public Shape
{
  public:
    Polygon(int sides);
    virtual ~Polygon();

    void draw();

private:
  vector<Coordinates *> verticies;

};
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
    vector <GLCommand*> vec;
    Polygon p(4);

    vec.push_back(&p);

    for (vector<GLCommand*>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it!=vec.end(); ++it)
    {
      *it->draw();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your code. You have a vector of *pointers*, not of "abstract classes".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing you said is relevant; the problem is just operator precedence:

```
(*it)->draw();
```

Comment: Would it be possible to explain to me why the parentheses are required here?  The only time I've seen a pointer dereferenced like this is when you use the dot notation to call a member function eg: (*ptr).foo();

Comment: The dereference-operator simply has lower precedence than the `->` member access operator, so `*it->x` is `*(it->x)`, and not `(*it)->x`. Similarly, `*ptr.foo()` is `*(ptr.foo())`, not `(*ptr).foo()`.

Answer (score 1):

Put parentheses in the right place:

```
(*it)->draw();
```

Or, to avoid these issues, use boost::ptr_vector when your container carries ownership of its objects.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted its precedence.

But you can use the STL algorithms to achieve the affect you need much easier:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::mem_fun(&GLCommand::draw));
```